# Pass a table name to INSERT INTO tablename from outside or a variable?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, dapper

I have more tables with great number of entries in production that I want to move to history database.

I have tried to use this query that works fine but I don't know if there is a possibility to give a name of a tables from outside. I don't want to write this query for every database and table.

```
INSERT INTO [database.history].dbo.tablename
SELECT *
FROM [database.live].dbo.table

DELETE FROM [database.history].dbo.tablename
```

I want to give names of databases and tables from the outside. I use dapper ORM. Is there any solution to use something similar to other types? For example.

```
DECLARE @ProductionTableName nvarchar(250) = '[database.live].dbo.table'
```

My databases are on the same server.

My queries are in files and I my call looks something like.

```
string query = queryFile;
var param = new {Parameter1= stringValue};
var result = Connection.Query<long>(query, param);
```

Comment: So you won't perform operation 1st DB to 2nd DB in c# side?

Comment: You can't really do that directly without using dynamic SQL.  However, you could have if-else logic which checks for an incoming table name from the outside, and, based on that, runs a certain insert statement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the answer. That is also an option.

Comment: @jishansiddique no. I want to use raw sql.

Comment: Based on the syntax I've added the `tsql` and `sql server` tags to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't parameterize identifiers in SQL. What you can do is use dynamic SQL.
Please note, however, that using dynamic SQL might be dangerous unless done correctly.

The basic rule is actually very simple - You must parameterize what you can, and white-list what you can't.
For more details, read my blog post [The do’s and don’ts of dynamic SQL for SQL Server.](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/12/the-does-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql-for-sql-server-%EF%BB%BF/)

Also, since you're moving records from one table to another you should use a transaction, otherwise, if your delete statement fails with an error, the insert statement will not be rolled back, and you will end up with the rows that lives in both databases.
For more information, read [Understanding Cross-Database Transactions in SQL Server](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/understanding-cross-database-transactions-in-sql-server/) over on red-gate.

Please note that if the history database is on a different server then the live database, you will need a [distributed transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/distributed-transactions).

A working example would be something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @TableName sysname = 'TableName',
        @LineBreak nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10),
        @Sql nvarchar(4000);

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM [database.live].Information_schema.Tables
    WHERE Table_Name = @TableName
)
BEGIN

    SET @SQL = 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' + @LineBreak + 
    'BEGIN TRY' + @LineBreak + 
    'INSERT INTO [database.history].dbo.' + @TableName + @LineBreak + 
    'SELECT *' + @LineBreak + 
    'FROM [database.live].dbo.' + @TableName + @LineBreak +

    'DELETE FROM [database.history].dbo.' + @TableName + 
    'COMMIT TRANSACTION' + @LineBreak + 
    'END TRY' + @LineBreak + 
    'BEGIN CATCH' + @LineBreak + 
    'IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0' + @LineBreak + 
    '    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION' + @LineBreak + 
    'END CATCH' + @LineBreak

    -- When working with dynamic SQL, Print is your best friend.
    PRINT @SQL
    -- Once you've verified that the SQL looks ok, you can unremark the EXEC statemet.
    --EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @SQL
END
```

Please note, however, that it's considered bad practice to use an `insert` statement without specifying the columns list, as well as using `select *`.
To add that to your query, you can query `sys.columns` to get the columns of the table you want.

I've also noticed that the code in the question doesn't contain a `where` clause - meaning the entire content of the row will be moved from live database to history database.

Comment: He mentioned that he is using Dapper.

Comment: @ЛюсиенЛозанов that's great but irrelevant to my answer. I'm showing how to do this purely in TSQL. Run it from dapper, run it from SSMS, use powershell - it doesn't matter.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for the detailed answer. I do have transaction and Where clause but I didn't write  it because I wanted to simplified the question. But thanks for the warning I will try your example and I will inform you about my results.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for the answer. It did solve my problem and I have marked It as the right answer. It has slipped my mind that I can build dynamic queries.One question. Why is it a bad practice to use insert into without specifying the columns?

Answer (score 1):

If you`re using Dapper that means you're using the queries in the c# code, not in stored procedures. You can add your ProdDb and HistoryDb in your app.config and use it from there.

edit: You can build also different connection strings for both DBs and open whatever connection you want to use in your code.

If your databases are on the same server you can use the [SQL Server Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) feature to replicate production DB to history DB.

Comment: SQL Server Replication is not available for me. With the app.config, I am not clear what have you thought. I still need to pass somehow values for table names in INSERT INTO and FROM in a raw sql and you they are not strings.

Comment: @Sead Avdic if you`re using Dapper you can add variables to Execute method, right? Then you can access your app.settings values and pass them to the Dapper query

Comment: Yes I can do that. I have edit the question but I can pass for example string values and not table names that are expected in raw sql.It is not relevant on which database I connect. I still need access to two different databases in one query.

Comment: @Sead Avdic You can also make different connection strings. Check edited answer.